# Stale reference when sorting EXT grid with webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have encountered a state reference when sorting a grid and asserting that no error error dialogs are displayed (this is a common error in the application I am testing).  I found a way around this but I guess there must be better solution.  I am currently reinstanciating the object grid headers after each click on the column header which seems a bad way of doing this to me.  What would be a better way of doing this

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     gridHeaders = this.getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("<grid headers>"));
     gridHeaders.get(i).click();
     assertNumberOfElements(By.cssSelector("div.errorDialog"), 0);
     gridHeaders = this.getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector("<grid headers>"));
     gridHeaders.get(i).click();
     assertNumberOfElements(By.cssSelector("div.errorDialog"), 0);
}
```

Comment: There's no way to get around that StaleElement exception, to the best of my knowledge. Once you navigate to a different page (and when you click an element, that's what happens), all the previous elements that you found are "potentially stale".

Comment: Second thought... see answer below...

Answer (score 0):

You can first iterate all these elements and get their "href" targets or whatever it is that redirects you when you click on them.

Then, after saving all these strings (which unlike Selenium Web Elements cannot become "stale"), you can navigate to each URL separately, using `webDriver.get()` or `webDriver.navigate().to()` (which are essentially identical operations).